# CS50 Python course, LittleProfessor Question - why is my code failing the "generate addition problems" tests?

Tags: python, random, cs50

The question wants the user to input a level between 1 and 3. Based on this input, generate addition problems with 1, 2 or 3 digit integers respectively, chosen at random. My code seems to do this just fine, but is failing the checks. The code error that is being displayed is:

```
:( At Level 1, Little Professor generates addition problems using 0–9
    Did not find "6 + 6 =" Choose Level "C: 8 + 7 = "
:( At Level 2, Little Professor generates addition problems using 10–99
    Did not find "59 + 63 =" in "Choose Level: 85 + 78 = ..."
:( At Level 3, Little Professor generates addition problems using 100–999
    Did not find "964 + 494 =" in "Choose Level: 859 + 782 ..."
```

Here is my code:

```
import random

def main():
    level = get_level()
    score = 0
    for i in range(10):
        x, y = generate_integer(level)
        answer = x + y

        for j in range(3):
            print(x, "+", y, "= ", end="")
            guess = int(input())
            if guess == answer:
                score = score + 1
                break
            elif guess != answer and j == 2:
                print(x, "+", y, "=", answer)
                break
            else:
                print("EEE")
    print("Score:", score)



def get_level():
    while True:
        try:
            n = int(input("Choose Level: "))
            if 1 <= n <= 3:
                return n
        except ValueError:
            pass

def generate_integer(level):
    if level == 3:
        return random.choices(range(100, 1000), k=2)
    elif level == 2:
        return random.choices(range(10, 100), k=2)
    elif level == 1:
        return random.choices(range(0, 10), k=2)
    else:
        raise ValueError

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code using Python 3.10 and it runs without issues. However, your codes does have issues with Python 2, namely:

- `print`'s optional argument `end` is not available.
- `choices` is not part of `random`.
- The formatting of the printed operations now includes unwanted `(` and such.

Once I removed `end` and replaced the call to `choices` by some random 2-tuple, the code ran fine.

The output you provide (which I assume is the output given by whatever test code calls your own code) doesn't give any helpful details. My guess is that the test uses Python 2 and simply fails because of the issues mentioned above. If you don't have direct access to the test code, adapt your own to run in Python 2. If you do have access, explicitly run it using `python3`.